# An ipad app or setting that helps turn off wifi or turn on airplane mode on schedule?

Tags: ipad, battery

i hope to conserve battery at night. is there an ipad app or setting that helps turn off wifi or turn on airplane mode at certain time? or would it even be better to have an app that turns off the device completely on schedule?

Comment: Not without jailbreaking your device. Neither of those features are normally available to 3rd-party apps.

Comment: @DanJ this seems it could be a legitimate app, i wonder why no one has thought about it.

Comment: Keep in mind, that someone can't create an app like this (except for jailbreak tweaks which may exist) because these are system level processes, and, for the most part, iOS apps aren't allowed to to modify or control system level processes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Not unless you jailbreak your device.

There is obviously Do-Not-Disturb which disables *alerts*, but does not put the phone on Airplane mode or disable wifi.

Keep in mind that if you turn off wifi, or enable Airplane mode, that iCloud backups or iTunes backups won't work at that point.

So, in order to conserve battery overnight, you will need to manually enable Airplane mode, disable wifi, or, you could power the device off completely. Again, keep in mind, iCloud backups will not perform during this time.